# Reference to a reference in SML

Tags: reference, sml

I was studying references in SML.

I wrote the following code:

```
let
    val f = (fn (s) => s := ref((!(!s)) + 2))
    val x = ref (5)
    val y = ref x
in
    (f y ; !x)
end;
```

I'm trying to get to `val it = 7 : int`, although my program prints `val it = 5 : int`. I can't understand why. I am sure the problem is in the `f` function but can't understand why.

What I'm trying to do: `f` function should update the argument `y` to be `ref(ref(7))` so `x` could be `ref(7)`. but for some reason it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Updating y to point to a new ref does not update x. There's a new reference created during the call to f, let's call it z. Before the call we have:

```
x -> 5
y -> x
```

where `->` is "points to". After the call it is:

```
x -> 5
y -> z
z -> 7
```

Edit: One possible way to actually update x is by defining f as follows:

```
val f = fn r => !r := 7
```

When invoking f y, this updates the reference *pointed to* by y, which is x. But whether that is the "right" solution depends on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Are you implying it impossible to make to program print `val it = 7 : int`?

Comment: Well, there are many ways to make it result in 7, it depends on what exactly you want to achieve. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas Rossberg suggests, `val f = fn r => !r := 7` could be one way to update the *int* of an *int ref ref* to 7. But instead of `7` you could write anything. If, instead, you want to increase by two the *int* being pointed indirectly to, a hybrid between your attempt and Andreas'es suggestion could be

```
fun f r = !r := !(!r) + 2
```

Here, `!r := ...` means "dereference `r` to get the *int ref* it points to, and update that *int ref* so that it instead points to `...`", and `!(!r) + 2` means "dereference `r` twice to get the *int* it indirectly points to, and add two to it." At this point, you have not changed what `r` points to (like you do with `s := ref ...`), and you're using the value it points to indirectly using the double-dereference `!(!r)`.

A test program for this could be:

```
val x = ref 5
val y = ref x
fun f r = !r := !(!r) + 2

fun debug str =
    print ( str ^ ": x points to " ^ Int.toString (!x) ^ " and "
          ^ "y points indirectly to " ^ Int.toString (!(!y)) ^ ".\n" )

val _ = debug "before"
val _ = f y
val _ = debug "after"
```

Running this test program yields:

```
before: x points to 5 and y points indirectly to 5.
after: x points to 7 and y points indirectly to 7.
```